# mongodb query for date fields

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo

I save a mongodb field '**date**' as datetime object
and use following queries

```
1.db.test_collection.find({'date': {'$gte': start_date_time}})
2. db.test_collection.find({"date": {"$gte": start_date_time, "$lte": end_date_time}
```

where start_date_time is (say)2014-06-03 00:00:00 and end_date_time 2014-06-03 23:59:59
 i insert some values to mongodb, But I don't give any results.
please help me to solve the issue.

Comment: Show your document. Your "date" field is possibly a string.

Comment: sample value in my db is datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 4, 3, 47, 25, 637000)

Comment: That isn't a document. You can actually **edit** your post to show what the document actually looks like.

Comment: @ Neil Lunn, thanks for your helping attitude. Actaully there was no error in my script> I used datetime.datetime.now() to save date to db, But apache time different from server time!. now I use datetime.datetime.utcnow(). The problem fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `datetime` type.

```
import datetime

db.test_collection.find({'date': {'$gte': datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 3, 16, 46) }})
```

You can see more in the documentation (http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/tutorial.html)

Hope it works fine for you!

Comment: start_date_time am using is a datetime object